# Connect Manager shows no update, how to upgrade manually?

Tags: upgrade, downloader

I want to upgrade my Magento installation from 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3.2, and all online resources tell me it should be done through the Connect Manager. But the Connect Manager doesn't show an update on `Mage_All_Latest`. And documentation on how to upgrade using the bzip2 package I cannot find.

Any help on either fixing the Connect Manager, or installing 1.9.3.2 manually?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to merge new version source with old version. Before it, disable compilation and all caches. Don't forget to take backup of database and source too. And at last hard reload(refresh) the frontend and wait for upgrade.

Comment: So, basically just overwrite the existing tree with the one in the zip package?

Comment: Yes. But for safe side, don't forget to take backup of old system including source and database.